# Style sheet in express static folder

Tags: node.js, express, static, stylesheet

I have set the static folder like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

And referenced the style sheet (which can be found in "public/stylesheets") like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
```

And it works fine on localhost:3500/ and on localhost:3500/items, but when i go on localhost:3500/items/get, it searches for the style sheet in "items/stylesheets". What should I do, so the "public" library stays the same wherever I am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a forward slash so it always searches relative to the root of your website

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answer, provide explanations on what's different from the code in the question and why this should work for future readers. Also note that the green tick next to the other answer means that it resolved the problem (4 years ago).

Comment: Thanks  "Mickael B" for the suggestions. I'm new to Stack Owerflow. I tried the previous answer and it didn't work for me. I just wanted to to write an option that worked for me.